# Is this line of the code is type name; ?(CPP LIO-SAM open-code)

Tags: c++, macros

I am studying LIO-SAM open code. Since I am not good at cpp, I have few question about cpp code.

```
    struct VelodynePointXYZIRT
    {
        PCL_ADD_POINT4D
        PCL_ADD_INTENSITY;
        uint16_t ring;
        float time;
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
     } EIGEN_ALIGN16;
    POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (VelodynePointXYZIRT,
        (float, x, x) (float, y, y) (float, z, z) (float, intensity, intensity)
        (uint16_t, ring, ring) (float, time, time)
    )

    struct OusterPointXYZIRT {
        PCL_ADD_POINT4D;
        float intensity;
        uint32_t t;
        uint16_t reflectivity;
        uint8_t ring;
        uint16_t noise;
        uint32_t range;
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
     } EIGEN_ALIGN16;
    POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT(OusterPointXYZIRT,
        (float, x, x) (float, y, y) (float, z, z) (float, intensity, intensity)
        (uint32_t, t, t) (uint16_t, reflectivity, reflectivity)
        (uint8_t, ring, ring) (uint16_t, noise, noise) (uint32_t, range, range)
    )
```

In this code, I found out that PCL_ADD_POINT4D is union defined in pcl library.

```
    #define PCL_ADD_UNION_POINT4D \
    union EIGEN_ALIGN16 { \
        float data[4]; 
        struct { \
         float x; \
         float y; \
         float z; \
         }; \
       };

     #define PCL_ADD_EIGEN_MAPS_POINT4D \
       inline pcl::Vector3fMap getVector3fMap () { return (pcl::Vector3fMap (data)); } \
       inline pcl::Vector3fMapConst getVector3fMap () const { return (pcl::Vector3fMapConst (data)); } \
       inline pcl::Vector4fMap getVector4fMap () { return (pcl::Vector4fMap (data)); } \
       inline pcl::Vector4fMapConst getVector4fMap () const { return (pcl::Vector4fMapConst (data)); } \
       inline pcl::Array3fMap getArray3fMap () { return (pcl::Array3fMap (data)); } \
       inline pcl::Array3fMapConst getArray3fMap () const { return (pcl::Array3fMapConst (data)); } \
       inline pcl::Array4fMap getArray4fMap () { return (pcl::Array4fMap (data)); } \
       inline pcl::Array4fMapConst getArray4fMap () const { return (pcl::Array4fMapConst(data)); }
      
     #define PCL_ADD_POINT4D \
       PCL_ADD_UNION_POINT4D \
       PCL_ADD_EIGEN_MAPS_POINT4D
```

My question is in the third line of the code, I think PCL_ADD_POINT4D should be PCL_ADD_POINT4D; . If PCL_ADD_INTENSITY's type is union PCL_ADD_POINT4D (ex. type name; such as int a;)then 15th line of the code is still questionable to me.

My second question is What is POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT ? Is it function? Can you tell be a keyword so that I can google it.

Sorry for stupid question... and Thank you for kindness answers in advance.

The full code is in https://github.com/TixiaoShan/LIO-SAM/blob/master/src/imageProjection.cpp#L5

Answer (score 0):

This macro

```
PCL_ADD_POINT4D
```

according to its definition, expands to

```
PCL_ADD_UNION_POINT4D \
PCL_ADD_EIGEN_MAPS_POINT4D
```

which in turn expands to

```
[...]
inline pcl::Vector3fMap getVector3fMap () { return (pcl::Vector3fMap (data)); } \
inline pcl::Vector3fMapConst getVector3fMap () const { return (pcl::Vector3fMapConst (data)); } \
inline pcl::Vector4fMap getVector4fMap () { return (pcl::Vector4fMap (data)); } \
inline pcl::Vector4fMapConst getVector4fMap () const { return (pcl::Vector4fMapConst (data)); } \
inline pcl::Array3fMap getArray3fMap () { return (pcl::Array3fMap (data)); } \
inline pcl::Array3fMapConst getArray3fMap () const { return (pcl::Array3fMapConst (data)); } \
inline pcl::Array4fMap getArray4fMap () { return (pcl::Array4fMap (data)); } \
inline pcl::Array4fMapConst getArray4fMap () const { return (pcl::Array4fMapConst(data)); }
```

There is no `;` required after definition of a method in a class. Simpler example

```
 #define foo_method  void foo() {}

 struct bar {
     foo_method
 };
```

After the preprocessor the code is this:

```
 struct bar {
     void foo() {}
 };
```

To know what `POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT` is you need to search for its definition in the code base. Macros can be used and abused to do the most weirdest things. It could really be anything.

Don't confuse preprocessor macros with actual code.

> In this code, I found out that PCL_ADD_POINT4D is union defined in pcl library.

No. `PCL_ADD_POINT4D` is a preprocessor symbol, that when used in code is expanded by the preprocessor by the definition of the union. This distinction is essential, because the preprocessor runs before the actual compilation starts. It is merely about textual replacement of tokens.

Comment: Um.. can you tell be the difference between  PCL_ADD_POINT4D in 3rd line of the code and PCL_ADD_POINT4D in 15th line of the code??

Comment: @BBak there is no difference its the same preprocessor symbol. A `;` after a method definition is superfluous but not an error https://godbolt.org/z/4j4s3bqq8